# How to select from string charcters ending with a letter and number

Tags: r, string, ends-with

I have this kind of dataset

```
mtcars$drat1 = mean(mtcars$drat)
mtcars$wt1 = mean(mtcars$wt)
```

I have been trying to build up the code following the rule so that it selects the every element  finishing with t and a number.

I have tried this code but I am getting an empty object.

```
mtcars %>% dplyr::select(ends_with('t[0-9]$'))
```

How should I modify this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/starts_with.html) states, the argument for `starts_with()`, `ends_with()`, and `contains()` looks for an *exact* match. You want to use `matches()` here, which can accept regex:

```
mtcars %>% dplyr::select(matches('t[0-9]$'))

#                       drat1     wt1
# Mazda RX4           3.596563 3.21725
# Mazda RX4 Wag       3.596563 3.21725
# Datsun 710          3.596563 3.21725
# Hornet 4 Drive      3.596563 3.21725
# ...
```

Or in base R:

```
mtcars[grep("t[0-9]$", names(xx))]
```

Comment: Thanks. Why in this case the function ends_with() does not work?

Comment: Because it is looking for the literal string "t[0-9]$" - not what that means in regular expressions.